# Show Facebook wall on website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to show your facebook wall on a website? I have been looking for days and all I can find is methods of showing ones OWN messages. Im looking for something(script/code) that will show the complete wall including what friends are posting. Is this even possible or is it prohibited by Facebook? I did search there 'developers api site' but couldnt find an anwser to this.

Comment: No.. there is no official way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but you need to build your own custom version as officially facebook doesn't provide any pre-built plugins or code.

You'll have to code a lot of back-end and front-end stuffs. If you're really interested in building something like that, you might wanna consider looking at this script [Facebook Wall Script 3.0 with PHP and Jquery](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/05/facebook-wall-script-with-php-and.html)

If you want to save time, you might buy that script, do the necessary changes and integrate facebook graph API so it shows data from your fb profile, but if you want build more advance version and have lot of time, then you can build a custom version from scratch.

Comment: Im not sure what is going on on that link of yours. Its seems to me its something that 'looks' like facebook wall rather than the actual facebook wall.

Comment: As i said, You can't add 'actual' facebook wall to your site, that's not possible, but you can surely custom code it and that link has a similar design and system like facebook, so you could use that script and build your own facebook wall on your site.

Answer (score 0):

i don't see the point of show your facebook wall on a website since can have that easily by pointing the user back to your facebook account.

i would suggest you to display a facebook page plugin instead as you can earn some like and it is free of charge.

could you let me know why you want to do that?

Comment: Hi, Im designing a 'starting page' like Yahoo.com So I want to let visitors have the ability to view there wall without having to go to facebook